# Maven: is there a simple command to test repository access?

Tags: maven, nexus

Some of my users have trouble accessing our local Nexus repository. Some of them are somewhat newbies in maven configuration. Sure they can test if everything is downloading fine running `mvn install`, but I'd like to help them to isolate their environment problems.

Is there a simple mvn command just to test if the repository access is correctly configured?

Comment: The simplest test is to run a `mvn clean` which downloads plugins etc.

Comment: BTW: You should teach your colleagues not to start using `mvn install` better `mvn package` and teach them the differences...

Comment: Agree with mvn clean.. otherwise having a wget or curl command can provide quick http-level checking

Comment: @khmarblaise, would you put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple

```
mvn clean
```

test the repository access.

Comment: I've intentionally borked the repository URL in my settings.xml file and `mvn clean` does not report any issues.

Comment: I tried it with invalid password. Maybe does not work with invalid repo? I don't have a place to test now.

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

Comment: This one is better if you do not have a project setup yet but just want to check the repo you have configured (your company's repo in settings.xml for example).
You may clean the m2 folder and see then dependencies getting downloaded again from the configured repo.

Answer (score 0):

I had a number of dependencies that failed to download from the Maven Central repository (apparently due to network throttling/flakiness). Running "mvn clean" just immediately returned with the same errors, obviously not attempting any more downloads. But its message said to rerun with "-x" option to see the full stack trace, so I ran:

```
mvn clean -x
```

This caused it to retry and download more. It took several tries to get all dependencies downloaded, but it did eventually run to completion. It didn't give me any stack traces, and I still don't know what was causing the failures (the repository was reachable the whole time).